# Menu bar over sized the width of screen ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity

After I restart my computer, the screen display below
[image]

And all application windows such as Chrome ... are not displayed full.
When I logon other user, the screen display well.

How to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Here is `xrandr` output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02* 
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Try opening **Settings > Displays** and setting a correct screen resolution.

Comment: I tried it, problem was fixed but it displayed too large and ugly

Comment: May be it's not the suitable resolution. What is brand and model of your display? Edit your question, posting `xrandr`output.

Comment: @Redbob I have updated `xrandr` output

Comment: OK, but what display device do you have?

Comment: A LG monitor 17". But when i logon other user, the problem is fixed.

Comment: For a 17" monitor, the normal resolution would be 1024x768. If you choose a higher resolution, you may have to adjust the monitor's internal display height and width, using the monitor's menu system.